# grails 3 json serializer no class attribute

Tags: json, grails

Is there a reason why the class attribute is not rendered in Json anymore in grails 3? I use grails 3.3
Example:

Domainclass

```
Class A {    
   String name 
}
```

then:

```
A a = new A(name: "test")
JSON.use('deep') {
    render a as JSON
}
```

gives me:

```
{
   a: "test"
}
```

In older versions i can rember, that always the attribute "class" with the classname was rendered within this json. There are a lot of questions on how to get rid of this. But I have the opposite need: I need this class attribute.

Is there any way to get back to this behaviour without writing my own serializer?

Answer (score 0):

Set `grails.converters.domain.include.class` to `true`

The change was made back in Dec 2015. https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-plugin-converters/commit/d7ef874a59e19abc03821181ff33e11f612c63a6